# Google Apps Script button you can click more than once

Tags: events, button, google-apps-script

I can't figure out how to make my button to continue to be 'click-able' to run the code that I want it to run.

I basically have a button that when it's pressed it will give you the first item on a list, prints the item, and then moves the item to the end of the list. If the user presses the button again, the item that is now first on the list is printed and then moved to the end of the list. The script should keep doing this every time the button is pressed. I can only get the button to run the script once and I'm not sure what is making it non-clickable.

The app is a stand-alone script. Any help is appreciated. Thank you! -- Here is the code:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Next Provider');
  var button = app.createButton("Show Next Provider");

  var providers = ["Provider1", "Provider2","Provider3", "Provider4", "Provider5"]
  var provider = providers[0]

  var label = app.createLabel("Please schedule patient with: " + provider)
                 .setId('statusLabel')
                 .setVisible(false);
  app.add(label);

  var handler = app.createServerHandler('myClickHandler');
  button.addClickHandler(handler);

  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  panel.add(button);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;

  providers.splice(0,1)
  providers.push(provider)

}

function myClickHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  var label = app.getElementById('statusLabel');
  label.setVisible(true);

  app.close();
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Click handler is not doing what you say its doing (instead doGet is doing it.)
You need to do that correctly and also dont call app.close.